# PHP Reg Ex how to preg_match exactly 2 or 3 digits in a street address

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to figure out the reg ex to match a street address. The format of the street address must be 2 or 3 digit number followed by a text string of the street name then ending with "Street" or "Road".

So a valid address can be:

- 12 Fake Street
- 12 fake Road
- 123 fake Street
- 123 fake Road

Invalid address would be:

- 1 fake Street
- 1 fake Road
- 1234 fake Street
- 1234 fake Road

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]{2,3} *[a-zA-Z] *(Street|Road)$/", $_POST['street'])
```

I've tried multiple ways to approach this and can't get the digits in to work correctly.
If I try `/^[0-9]{2,3}$/` it works by itself but when I add in the string expressions, it messes it up. Also using that formula without ^ or $, it'll validate any amount of digits beyond 3 digits long. So 1234, 12345, etc will work.

Comment: Why is "1 fake street" invalid in your eyes? for that matter, why is four digits not acceptable either?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The number has to be exactly 2 or 3 digits long (second sentence).

Comment: @ComFreek But why? Addresses can have any number of digits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have correct regex to match street name that comes after first digits since `[a-zA-Z]` **will match single alphabet only**

Use this regex:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]{2,3} +[a-zA-Z]+ +(Street|Road)$/", $_POST['street']);
```

Difference is `[a-zA-Z]+` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`

PS: Also changes to `+` instead of `*` since at least 1 space is needed between these components.